# Javascript slide effect onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, mootools, slide, effect

I'd like to add a slide & fade effect to a DIV, with purely Javascript, using "onclick".

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TCUd5/

The DIV that has to slide has id="pulldown_contents_wrapper".
This DIV is contained in a SPAN, that also triggers it:

```
<span onclick="toggleUpdatesPulldown(event, this, '4');" style="display: inline-block;" class="updates_pulldown" >
    <div class="pulldown_contents_wrapper" id="pulldown_contents_wrapper">
```

And I think the JS code that controls the SPAN onclick is:

```
var toggleUpdatesPulldown = function(event, element, user_id) {
  if( element.className=='updates_pulldown' ) {
    element.className= 'updates_pulldown_active';
    showNotifications();
  } else {
    element.className='updates_pulldown';
  }  
}
```

If it is not possible to make it with pure JS, do you have an idea how could I do it with Mootools? (*I'd like to use only pure JS or the Mootols framework).

I have tried to implement the code from: [why javascript onclick div slide not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702266/why-javascript-onclick-div-slide-not-working)  but with no results.

Thanks a lot.

I have managed to make it with Mootools, but I can't figure it out how to add a slide & fade effect, and a delay on mouseout

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        $('updates_pulldown').addEvents({
          mouseenter: function(){
            $('updates_pulldown').removeClass('updates_pulldown').addClass('updates_pulldown_active')
            $('pulldown_contents_wrapper').set('tween', {
              duration: 1000,
              physics: 'pow:in:out',
              transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut // This could have been also 'bounce:out'
            }).show();
          },
          mouseleave: function(){
            $('pulldown_contents_wrapper').set('tween', {
                duration: 1000,
                delay: 1000,
                }).hide();
            $('updates_pulldown').removeClass('updates_pulldown_active').addClass('updates_pulldown')
          },
        });
    });

  var toggleUpdatesPulldown = function(event, element, user_id) {
      showNotifications();
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why not use jQuery. It's also purely javascript, or am i missing something?

Comment: I am working on SocialEngine 4, it does not uses jQuery by default...it uses Mootols

Comment: You can find a couple of demos on [mootools.net](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Effects)

Comment: Thanks, I have already looked at all the demos possible, I just don't have any idea how to implement something that would work with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a lot easier, but with pure javascript you can do it.

In the CSS you'll need to use transitions

```
#thing { position:relative;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-transition: top 1s linear, opacity 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s linear, opacity 1s linear;
 }
```

then in the javascript when you change the position of the element, it should change via the css transitions.

```
var toggleUpdatesPulldown = function(event, element, user_id) {
  if( element.className=='updates_pulldown' ) {
     element.style.top = someValue; //something like '100px' will slide it down 100px
     element.style.opacity = '1.0'; //will fade the content in from 0.8 opacity to 1.0
     element.className= 'updates_pulldown_active';
    showNotifications();
```

**EDIT - provided jQuery code**

call the jQuery library, most easily done from the google hosting

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

make the hover function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.updates_pulldown').hover( //first function is mouseon, second is mouseout
            function() {
                $(this).animate({top: '50px'}).animate({opacity: '1.0'});
            },
            function() { //delay 1000 milliseconds, animate both position and opacity
                $(this).delay(1000).animate({top: '0px'}).animate({opacity: '0.5'});
            }
        )
    })
```

the function timing will be the same as whatever you set it to in the css with transition tags. using 'this' instead of the class name again makes sure that the effect only occurs on the specific instance of the class that is hovered over. im not sure if this animation is exactly what you were asking for, but if i understand the question correctly then the main functionality will work for you. just change the numbers and such to fit your needs.

Comment: Not really works. Do you have an idea how it can be done with Mootools?

Comment: I have managed to make it with Mootols somehow, but I still have to add some effects. I have edited the post...maybe you can help. Thank you.

Comment: if you are using mootools i dont really see why you need to change the elements class just for a hover event. mootools should be able to edit any css differences as well as the animation with this plugin: http://mootools.net/forge/p/fx_css. I would suggest using jQuery though, it is a lot more straightforward in my opinion and can do a lot more, especially in cases like this with use of the .hover(), .animate() and .delay() functions

Comment: Thanks, actually I know to use jQuery, but not Mootools. As I said now I work with SocialEngine, and it uses Mootools by default, so I'd like to use that and not to add another framework.