# Changing innerHTML of <p> element with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to webdesigning. What I am trying to accomplish is continuously change some text in `<p>` element with transition effect(some sort of slideshow).

Here's my code:

```
  <p id="qu">Some text</p>
   <script>
    var i = 0;
    function loop(){
        var text = ['new text 1', 'new text 2', 'new text 3']
        document.getElementById("qu").innerHTML = text[i];
        i = (i == 3)?0:i=i+1;
    }
    setInterval(loop, 1000);
    </script>
```

Now, My code is working fine but **How do I add 'slide in left' transition when innerHTML is changed?**

Comment: possibly a dublicate of [slide-effect onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980955/javascript-slide-effect-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/BgZE3/1/)

```
$('#qu').animate({'margin-left' : '-=40px'});
```

jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) lets you perform the required animations on your DOM elements.

---

Regular javascript:

```
margin = margin-40; //please add your parameter here.

document.getElementById("qu").style.marginLeft = (margin)+"px";
```

Comment: `OP` want to javascript solution

Comment: better now.., the code continuously adding text inside div element, this would be create issue in longer work..
if you can rotate all `text` array string that would great.