# Javascript "Maximum Call Size Stack Exceeded"

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a lock screen which takes "inspiration" from Windows 8. When the user clicks the image it slides up to reveal the password input field etc. I want the lock screen to "transition" or "animate" instead of just changing the display properties.

I've set up an event handler for the click which calls a function called SlideLockscreenUp. It's when I run this that I'm met with the "Maximum Call Size Stack Exceeded"  error. Initially my code was:

```
function slideLockscreenUp(){

    t = setTimeout(function(){
        ls.style.top = '-1%';
    }, 100);

    slideLockscreenUp();
}
```

When I first got the error I assumed it was because I hadn't set any condition for the recursion to stop, hence it would continue for ever forcing the browser to interfere.

So this is what I came up with next:

```
            function slideLockscreenUp(){

            do{
                t = setTimeout(function(){
                    ls.style.top = '-1%';
                }, 10);

                slideLockscreenUp();
            } while(ls.style.top < "-100%" );

        }
```

As you can see I test the display properties to stop the function when the position:top  is -100%. However I'm still getting the error and now I'm slightly confused as to why. Any help would be great!

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded. The `setTimeout` function will never get a chance to run as long as the `while` loop is running.

Comment: Hmm. Is there any other loop I could use that would get around this? Thanks

Comment: The best solution is to make use of CSS transitions rather than trying to do it in Javascript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980955/javascript-slide-effect-onclick/12981143#12981143

Answer (score 2):

You need the recursive call `slideLockscreenUp` to be inside the `setTimeout` callback function, otherwise it will be called multiple times before the first `setTimeout` callback is even called.

I suggest that you use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead of calling `setTimeout` multiple times.

```
function slideLockscreenUp(){

    t = setInterval(function(){
        ls.style.top = '-1%';

        if (/* exit condition */) {
            clearInterval(t);
        }
    }, 100);

}
```